# Why is the water still in the glass while rolling?

Tags: gravity, centrifugal-force

Pilot drinks glass of water while rolling the plane. The water stays in the glass, even if the plane is upside down.

How is this possible? Why doesn't the water leave the glass, as it does when I turn a glass upside down?

Link to video showing the phenomena: [http://i.imgur.com/SUXJKrP.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/SUXJKrP.gifv)

Comment: Please clarify your question in more details.

Comment: This is now done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is exactly the same as swinging a bucket of water in a vertical circle. The water will not fall out, if it is swung fast enough. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zjqrx7wrpJc

[image]
*[source](http://mail.colonial.net/~hkaiter/Gravity_Inertia.html)*

When you swing things around in circular orbits, it wants to fly "out of" the orbit.

- That is why water in the bucket is squeezing against the bucket which is the *opposite way of gravity* when the bucket is over your head.
- The same feeling is when your body presses against the door when the car turns. You body is set in motion and thus wants to continue moving, but the car forces the body to change direction (to turn along with the car).

So in that moment, you are pressed against the side of the car (the door) in the same manner as you are pressed against the ground by gravity in any normal situation.

It can therefore seem like "gravity acting sideways" on your body when a car turns. Or in the case of the water in the bucket it seems like "gravity acting upwards" on the water, when the bucket is above your head. And in the case of water poured into the cup in the spinning aircraft, it is exactly the same - it seems that "gravity acts downwards seen from the aircraft, even when the aircraft is turned up-side down".

But as explained this isn't gravity, but just the *tendency* of objects to continue on their path when they are set in motion. This feeling or tendency is in everyday terms named "*[centrifugal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force)*".

And all this will only work if gravity is overcome. Otherwise the water *would* just fall downwards (as if you swung the bucket of water to slowly).

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Centrifugal force that is created by the rolling counteracts gravity. If the pilot would do the roll over slower, the water would spill.

Comment: Your answer is a duplicate brief of @Steeven 's answer.

Comment: @lucas Correct. But when I started typing, the other answer wasn't there yet ;)